# Community ♦ user (bot) suggested a weird edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, community-user, anonymous-visitors

I just noticed that `Community ♦` suggested a weird edit:

> please explain what was wrong. thks mario

[Revision here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12106585/revisions)

Who's Mario..?
And why is the bot asking such a question?

### Summary:

what the deuce?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the edit was suggested by an anoymous user, and the OP accepted the edit, then the suggested edit had to be associated with a "real user" - which happens to be the role of Community in this case.

Comment: He must have *really* not been paying attention there.

Comment: Makes sense. Cheers. Whoever accepted must have wanted more info.

Comment: @James Commenting requires 50 rep. I would have expected it to be rejected in the suggested edits as an "attempt to comment..." *before* the OP had a chance to approve it though... (seems a little odd)