# Moderator diamond missing from iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators, display-names, ios-app

Related: [Missing Moderator's diamond in the Android application](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192018/missing-moderators-diamond-in-the-android-application). I considered editing the tags on that question to include [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app), but realized the accepted answer may not apply, so am posting as new question.

---

Appropriately enough, the first comment in this image which should have the diamond, from Robert Harvey, reads:

> There's a diamond next to my name. See it?

To which I definitively reply, *no!*

[image]

Comment: The unicorn chucked away his diamond :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

**Update:** More space, less ugly.

[image]

Comment: Ugh. There should really be a space of some kind between the name and the diamond.

Comment: @Undo True.  Added some space.

Comment: A bit of a tangent, but is it possible to prevent [the diamond character from being emjoified](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Hzw.png) in post content? (Example: [Community ♦ user (bot) suggested a weird edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220409))